# How do I get an individual value out of database using Moor_Flutter

Tags: android, database, flutter, dart, flutter-moor

I have a settings pages that uses a very simple database, which consists of a couple of tables to change the look and feel of a google map (google_maps_flutter). There is one more table, but that is used for something else within the app and I am not concerned with it here. I am using the moor_flutter and provider packages for this, but I am having a little difficulty returning a value.

What I want to do is to retrieve a boolean value (in this case) and display the SwitchListTile accordingly, but unfortunately, I can getting this error.

**NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List' has no instances getter 'tilt'.
Receiver: Instance(length:0) of '_GrowableList' Tried calling: tilt.
See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors**

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my table config

```
// Map Parameters table definition
class Parameters extends Table {
  BoolColumn get tilt => boolean().withDefault(Constant(true))();
  BoolColumn get traffic => boolean().withDefault(Constant(false))();
  BoolColumn get compass => boolean().withDefault(Constant(true))();
  BoolColumn get rotate => boolean().withDefault(Constant(true))();
  BoolColumn get zoom => boolean().withDefault(Constant(true))();
  /*TextColumn get type => text().named('normal')();
  TextColumn get area => text().named('Uni Campus')();*/
}
```

Here is my AppDatabase class

```
// App Database Class
@UseMoor(
    tables: [Parameters, Themes, Places],
    daos: [ParameterDao, ThemeDao, PlaceDao])
class AppDatabase extends _$AppDatabase {
  AppDatabase()
      : super(FlutterQueryExecutor.inDatabaseFolder(
            path: 'db.sqlite', logStatements: true));

  // Database Schema Version
  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 1; // Change this with every DB change

  @override
  MigrationStrategy get migration => MigrationStrategy(
    onUpgrade: (migrator, from, to) async{
      if(from == 1){
        // await migrator.addColumn(<table, <table>.<fieldName>);
        // await migrator.createTable(<table>);
      }
    },
    /*beforeOpen: (db,details) async {
      await db.customStatement('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');
    }*/
  );
}
```

Here is my Dao class

```
@UseDao(tables: [Parameters])
class ParameterDao extends DatabaseAccessor<AppDatabase> with _$ParameterDaoMixin {
  final AppDatabase db;

  ParameterDao(this.db) : super(db);

  // Map parameters queries
  Future<List<Parameter>> getAllParameters() => select(parameters).get();
  Stream<List<Parameter>> watchAllParameters() => select(parameters).watch();
  Future updateParameter(Parameter parameter, {bool tilt}) =>
      update(parameters).replace(parameter);
}
```

Here is the widget that contains my settings page

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dao = Provider.of<ParameterDao>(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: dao.watchAllParameters(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          bool _allowTilt = snapshot.data.tilt;
          bool _enableRotate = true;
          bool _enableZoom = true;
          bool _showTraffic = false;
          bool _showCompass = true;
          return Container(
            child: DecoratedBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
              ...
              ...
              ...
```

and here is my SwitchListTile

```
SwitchListTile(
    value: _allowTilt,
    onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
            // _allowTilt = value;
            //_db.updateParameter(tilt: _allowTilt);
            //print("ALLOW TILT => _allowTilt");
        });
    },
    title: Text(
        AppLocalizations.of(context).settingsLabelTilt),
    activeColor: Theme.UniColour.primary[900],
 ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this `bool _allowTilt = snapshot.data.tilt;` the line that causes the error?

Because it looks like you are trying to access the property `tilt` on the `snapshot.data`, but `data` should be a `List` according to your DAO.

The DAO returns a `Stream<List<Parameter>>` so your `data` is unwrapped to `List<Parameter>`.

If there is only ever one entry in the table you could access the entry by calling `first` on the list or you call `watchSingle()` in your DAO so that you only get one entry (will throw an exception if there is more than one entry in the table). Or you have to loop over the `data`.

By the way, `data` can be `null` and it is a good idea to check if the `snapshot.hasData` before accessing `data`.

Comment: Yes that is the line that causes the error. If I hard code a value, such as bool _AllowTilt = true, then all is good.

I will look into check that snapshot has data, but can data be null even with a default value? I thought I had added default values correctly.

Thanks lyio - I appreciate your time.